# Using importXML results in "Imported Content is Empty" error on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, bitcoin

**What I'm trying to do:**

Dynamically import the bitcoin/BTC price, from https://www.luno.com/en/price/, OR https://www.luno.com/en/price/BTC.

So I've read everything there is to read (on this site anyway) about `importXML`, and cannot find what I'm doing wrong. My method works on other websites, where I get a list of expected results, however, using `importXML` is not working. See below code I'm using (I've used other variants, but this is the one suggested using `SelectorGadget`:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.luno.com/en/price/", "//*[contains(concat( ' ', @class, ' ' ), concat( ' ', 'ng-binding', ' ' ))]")
```

Of course, I get the dreaded " **Imported Content is Empty** " error.

Any help?

Comment: Nothing. I tried to add, but it wouldn't let me add anything useful, and suggested angularjs, failing, it would not accept my post.

Answer (score -1):

You can load this ajax endpoint to get the current USD:

`https://www.luno.com/ajax/1/display_ticker`

or for all currency pairs:

`https://www.luno.com/ajax/1/price_chart?currency=`

if your want to parse the json - there is a wonderful - already written importJson script (https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs), you literally just copy paste it into your apps script and then call the url directly as such:

`=importJSON("https://www.luno.com/ajax/1/price_chart?currency=")`

or

`=importJSON("https://www.luno.com/ajax/1/display_ticker?currency=XBT")`

[image]

[image]